# A word to describe a day where I learned a lot

Tags: adjectives

I want a word to describe a day where I learned a lot. I can't think of many good choices. I was thinking productive or industrious, but that describes more the act of doing rather than learning.

Comment: You mean ***when** I learned a lot*, not *where*.

Comment: Yes. Yes, I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try an 'educational day.' You might also like enlightening, revealing, eye-opening, informative, enriching or illuminative.

Comment: Not quite so common as *educational*, perhaps, but *it was [an instructive day*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an+instructive+day%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) works just as well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[training day](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Training+day)**

> a day on which a military company assembles for drill or parade